# How to detect IP adress in ping string using regex

Tags: java, regex

```
String s = "PING www.google.com (173.194.70.106) 56(84) bytes of data."
boolean z = pattern.matches("\\(([0-9]{1,3}\\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\\)", s);
```

z will be 0. Where am I making a mistake given that the sequence that I am trying to detect is (X.X.X.X) so for `s` that would be `(173.194.70.106)`?

`egrep -e "\(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\)"` test gives the desired result so I assume it's a problem between me and java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`matches()` will try to match the whole string on the regular expression.

For your purpose you could use `Matcher.find()`:

```
String s = "PING www.google.com (173.194.70.106) 56(84) bytes of data.";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\(([0-9]{1,3}\\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\\)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

Comment: so if s had the value `(173.194.70.106)` then matches would have returned true?

Comment: @user3725793 Yes. You could also theoretically add `.*` at the beginning and end of your regular expression than it would match your input too.